# What is ISCL in terms of TCP

Tags: tcp

What is ISCL in terms of TCP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stands for  [Integrated Secure Communication Layer Protocols for Secure Medical Image Management Systems](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1999SPIE.3662..120K).

> ISCL is a security layer which manages
>   security function between presentation
>   layer and TCP/IP layer. ISCL mechanism
>   depends on basic function of a smart
>   IC card and symmetric secret key
>   mechanism. A symmetry key for each
>   session is made by internal
>   authentication function of a smart IC
>   card with a random number. ISCL has
>   three functions which assure
>   authentication, confidently and
>   integrity. Entity authentication
>   process is done through 3 path 4 way
>   method using functions of internal
>   authentication and external
>   authentication of a smart iC card.
>   Confidentially algorithm and MAC
>   algorithm for integrity are able to be
>   selected. ISCL protocols are
>   communicating through Message Block
>   which consists of Message Header and
>   Message Data. ISCL protocols are
>   evaluating by applying to regional
>   collaboration system for image
>   diagnosis, and On-line Secure
>   Electronic Storage system for medical
>   images.

Some more info can be found in [ISCL and DICOM Security](http://www.leadtools.com/SDK/Medical/Medical-Security-ISCL.htm). From what I can tell, it's basically an SSL protocol alternative that uses smart card instead of CA (certificate authority), invented by Japanese and used in Japan. Not sure how popular it is.